# Data Backup to AWS S3 using Backup Agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, amazon-s3, cloudberry

I am having cloudberry backup client, using which I need to backup some data. Consider the data to be backed up is 100 GB on a daily basis. I have 2 different use cases, to understand the number of requests and data transfer amount between the client app and S3. As data transfer IN is free from AWS side, I don't think backing up will be an issue, but restoring 100 GB would be charged, whenever done (correct me if I am wrong). Now, the use cases are:

1. Backup scheduled daily for 100 GB single file
2. Backup scheduled daily for 10 files each of 100 MB

Though I can get the pricing from AWS pricing page, I am trying to understand what would be my cost in this case (backing up to cloud).I would prefer to understand if pricing differs for file based, block based, image based backups etc. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: If you're restoring often enough that the cost matters, you probably need local backups. 9c/GB means 100GB is $9 to download everything. CloudBerry has block based backup, so it shouldn't backup everything each day, though I find their block based backups relatively ineffective compared with some other systems like Restic. You will pay per-request pricing for S3 uploads. You could use S3 intelligent tiering to reduce storage costs.

Comment: @Tim, I understand that. But I am trying to figure out the request pricing. Does a scheduled backup is counted as one single request though it is backing up 10 files, or is it totally counted as 10 requests?

Comment: No, have a read of the S3 pricing and documentation again again. The pricing is per API call. What CloudBerry will do is impossible to say, but for 10 files each 100MB with a block size of 10MB that's 10 x 10 x 10 requests = 1000 requests or $0.005c. If the block size is larger that might go down to $0.0005c. If CloudBerry takes it down to one 200MB file and you set a 200MB block size that's one request. The only way to know for sure is to try it a bunch of times and average it out, and counting these requests is fiddly, with CloudTrail.

Comment: All in all, the request pricing will be trivial, so I suggest you don't waste your time on it. Just make sure to configure CloudBerry to use large block sizes if you have a reliable internet connection. It's under tools -> options -> advanced -> block size.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks. Got an idea at least.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer, so you can close the question off.

Answer (score 0):

All in all, the request pricing will be trivial for this level of backups, so I suggest you don't waste your time on it.

After a few days or maybe a month you can get costs from cost explorer. Group by "Usage Type", select service S3. I looked at mine, my storage cost is about $1.05 a month with request cost $0.06. This is for a mix of archive storage, web server incremental backup, backup of some things on my PC every day using Cloudberry but not using incremental / block based backup.

Just make sure to configure CloudBerry to use large block sizes if you have a reliable internet connection. It's under tools -> options -> advanced -> block size